# In Java, I need to group the keys of a hash map based on the basis of their values

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, grouping, top-n

I need to find the topN keys.

I have an input as a HashMap in the form as (key : value):

```
Banana : 13  
Apple: 12  
Mango : 32  
Orange : 12  
Grape : 18  
Pear : 12  
Peach : 18
```

I created a linked HapMap that is sorted based on values:

```
private static <K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable> Map<K, V> sortByValues(Map<K, V> map) {
    List<Map.Entry<K, V>> entries = new LinkedList<Map.Entry<K, V>>(map.entrySet());

    Collections.sort(entries, new Comparator<Map.Entry<K, V>>() {

        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<K, V> o1, Map.Entry<K, V> o2) {
            return o2.getValue().compareTo(o1.getValue());
        }
    });
    Map<K, V> sortedMap = new LinkedHashMap<K, V>();
    for (Map.Entry<K, V> entry : entries) {
        sortedMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
    return sortedMap;
}
```

this gave my the output as:

```
Mango : 32  
Grape : 18  
Peach : 18  
Banana : 13  
Apple: 12  
Orange : 12  
Pear : 12
```

Now if I want to the Top-4 fruits, how should I approach if I want the output to be:

```
Mango :32  
Grape, Peach : 18  
Banana :13  
Apple, Orange, Pear: 12
```

I tried iterating through the sorted hashMap and compared the values of subsequent elements by doing

```
int sizeOfMap = myValueSortedMap.size();
ArrayList<String> keyArr = new ArrayList<String>();
int cnt=0,keyVal=0;

while(cnt<(sizeOfMap-1)){

    if(myValueSortedMap.values().toArray()[cnt] == myValueSortedMap.values().toArray()[cnt+1]){

        keyArr.add((String) myValueSortedMap.keySet().toArray()[cnt]+ " , " +(String) myValueSortedMap.keySet().toArray()[cnt+1]);
    }
    else{
        keyArr.add((String) myValueSortedMap.keySet().toArray()[cnt]);
        keyVal = (int) myValueSortedMap.values().toArray()[cnt];
    }
    cnt++;
}
```

but this does not always work.

I am not able to think of a way around this. Could someone please give me a lead?

Comment: You can try to reverse your Map. New map keys will be `number` values from the first map and new map values will be a `list` of first map keys having that value

Answer (score 8):

You can use a two-step stream process - the first step groups the entries by the numeric value, the second sorts the stream contents, applies the limit of 4 and prints the result.

```
map.entrySet()
   .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Map.Entry::getValue))
   // the map now contains integers mapped to a list of map entries
   .entrySet()
   .stream()
   // sort the stream by descending numeric value
   .sorted((o1, o2) -> o2.getKey().compareTo(o1.getKey()))
   // use the first four elements of the stream
   .limit(4)
   .forEach(entry -> System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " " + entry.getValue().stream().map(Map.Entry::getKey).collect(Collectors.joining(", "))));
```

This results in

```
32 Mango
18 Grape, Peach
13 Banana
12 Apple, Pear, Orange
```

Answer (score 2):

As I said in my comment, you will need to reverse your map first : so `Map<String, Integer>` will become `Map<Integer, List<String>>`.

Then, you can retrieve 4 max keys from your new map (formerly the values of your first map) and print their values

#### Map reverse method

```
public static <K extends Comparable, V extends Comparable> Map<V, List<K>> reverseMap(Map<K, V> map) {
    Map<V, List<K>> result = new HashMap<>();
    map.entrySet().stream().forEach((entry) -> {
        List<K> lst = result.get(entry.getValue());
        if (lst == null) {
            lst = new ArrayList<>();
            result.put(entry.getValue(), lst);
        }
        lst.add(entry.getKey());
    });
    return result;
}
```

#### How to use it

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Banana", 13);
map.put("Apple", 12);
map.put("Mango", 32);
map.put("Orange", 12);
map.put("Grape", 18);
map.put("Pear", 12);
map.put("Peach", 18); 

Map<Integer, List<String>> flip = reverseMap(map);

flip.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<Integer, List<String>>comparingByKey().reversed())
            .limit(4)
            .forEach(e -> System.out.println(String.join(", ", e.getValue()) + " : " + e.getKey()));
```

#### Here is the result

```
Mango : 32
Grape, Peach : 18
Banana : 13
Apple, Pear, Orange : 12
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate the `HashMap` and keep the first `k` elements.

```
private HashMap<String, Integer> select_k_element(HashMap sortedMap,int k){
    HashMap<String, Integer> res=new HashMap();
    int i=0;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        String key=e.getKey();
        int value=e.getValue();
        res.put(key,value);
        i++;
        if(i>=k)
            break;
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a `Map` with the key-value pair (datatypes) reversed. Following is a basic implementation:

```
private static Map<String, Integer> fruits = new HashMap<>();

static {
    fruits.put("Banana",13);  
    fruits.put("Apple", 12);
    fruits.put("Mango",32);
    fruits.put("Orange",12); 
    fruits.put("Grape",18);
    fruits.put("Pear",12);
    fruits.put("Peach",18); 
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeMap<Integer, String> freq = new TreeMap<>();

    // Populate the new Map
    fruits.entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        Integer key = e.getValue();
        if(freq.containsKey(key)) { // Update entry if key is already present
            String curVal = freq.get(key);
            String newVal = e.getKey();

            freq.put(key, curVal + ", " + newVal);
        } else { // Add an entry if key is not present
            freq.put(key, e.getKey());
        }
    });

    // Print the new Map
    freq.descendingMap().entrySet().forEach(e -> {
        System.out.println(e.getValue() + " : " + e.getKey());
    });
}
```

Used `TreeMap` to keep it sorted as per key and used `descendingMap()` to print it in descending order.

**Output:**

```
Mango : 32
Grape,Peach : 18
Banana : 13
Apple,Pear,Orange : 12
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SortedMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) with a "Fruit" Object implementing Compareable.

> The map is ordered according to the natural ordering of its keys, or by a Comparator typically provided at sorted map creation time. This order is reflected when iterating over the sorted map's collection views (returned by the entrySet, keySet and values methods). Several additional operations are provided to take advantage of the ordering. (This interface is the map analogue of SortedSet.)

Comment: `SortedMap<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();` - or see in javadoc the implementing classes of SortedMap. And iterate over the entrySet.